# Confused about the postfix increment operator and assignment operator precedence in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

The [operator precedence documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) says that the postfix increment operator have a higher precedence over the  assignment operator, but the following example shows that the opposite is true:

```
var i = 1;

var j = i++;

console.log(j);  // will output 1 (I expected the output to be 2)
```

Why the output is `1` instead of `2`?

Comment: Because it's the **post**-increment operator. The value is accessed **before** the increment happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The post-increment operator increments the value of the variable, but returns the value before it was incremented. Therefore, `j` will have a value of `1` while `i` will have a value of `2`.

```js
var i = 1;
var j = i++;
console.log("j =", j);
console.log("i =", i);
```

See [increment operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Increment):

> If used postfix, with operator after operand (for example, x++), the increment operator increments and returns the value before incrementing.
>
>  If used prefix, with operator before operand (for example, ++x), the increment operator increments and returns the value after incrementing.

Comment: Oh! I get it I think, so in `var j = i++;` **the `++` operator was indeed executed before the `=` operator**, but it's just that the `++` operator returns the old value of `i`. Am I correct?

Comment: @Steven Yes, that is correct.